# Riverpod Stream returning FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges() not working as it should

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I had a StreamBuilder that was returning FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges() and based on that navigating to login screen or home page, then I tried to move this code into a Riverpod provider to improve performance :

```
@riverpod
class AuthState extends _$AuthState {
  @override
  Stream<User?> build() {
    return FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges();
  }


}
```

Then I watched this provider in myApp like so:

```
class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final authstate = ref.watch(authStateProvider);
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: authstate,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            //Navigate to Home Page
            return MyHomePage();
          } else {
            //Navigate to Login Page
            return Login();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It should be working as it was before as all I have done is move FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges() to a Riverpod provider but now I get the error:

```
The argument type 'AsyncValue<User?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<User?>?'
```

When trying to pass it into the stream.

Comment: Correct.  The result of a StreamProvider is not a Stream.  It's the events from the stream.  You won't need your StreamBuilder any more... just a ref.watch and a dispatch based on `.when` acting on the result.

Comment: what is .when? I have not seen it before

Comment: It's a method on AsyncValue.  A StreamProvider produces AsyncValue objects, and you select actions based on those using .when.